# In AcetoneISO with Lubuntu I get error: no xorrisfs found in /usr/bin

Tags: lubuntu

In AcetoneISO I get error "no xorrisfs found in /usr/bin" when I try to "Generate ISO from folder"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install xorriso libisoburn1 libjte1
```

And try acetoniso